# ¿Calcular dos meses desde fecha insertada hasta fecha actual? Sí la cantidad de meses es mayor, ignorar

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    static function showNotificationStock()
    {
        $consultStock = "SELECT * FROM inv_productos WHERE stock <= 10 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fecha, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"; //sentencia query
        $data = Conexion::conectarEmpresa()->prepare($consultStock);
        $data -> execute();
        $showStock = $data -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
        $nueva = "";

        $response = [];
        $response['numIteration'] = $data -> rowCount();

        if($data -> rowCount() > 0){
            $text = "";
            foreach($showStock as $result){
                $responseStock = $result -> stock;
                $responseDescripcion = $result -> descripcion;
                $text .= "Te queda: <strong>" . $responseStock .  "</strong> " . $responseDescripcion . "<hr>"; # .= es concatenar contenido
            }
            $response['notification'] = $text;
            $response["nueva"] = "Nuevas notificaciones";

        }else{
            $response["nueva"] = "No hay notificaciones";
            $text = "Hoy no tienes notificaciones</p>";
            $response['notification'] = $text;
        }
        
        return $response;

}
```

Hola, deseo calcular dos meses desde el mes que se insertó un campo hasta la fecha actual, para así mostrar "X" producto. Pero no he tenido éxito en ello. Sé que hay una opción y es creando una tabla, pero no me sirve porque es cambiar todo el sistema que me entregaron.

Tengo aún conocimientos básicos en PHP y MYSQL.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para generar un reporte de búsqueda entre fechas yo utilizo la siguiente linea WHERE fecha BETWEEN CAST('$fechaInicio' AS DATE) AND CAST('$fechaFin' AS DATE)  $fechaInicio y $fechaFin se pasan como parámetros desde unos calendarios que funcionan con las librerías datatimepicker.  Estos se pueden configurar de diversas maneras para validar las entradas de las fechas.